# Is there a way to have a fast running query that's filtered on a column that is not indexed?

Tags: oracle, optimization

The title says it all: Is there a way to have a fast running query that's filtered on a column that is not indexed?

For example, I have query one like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST_TABLE
WHERE INDEXED_DATE_COLUMN BETWEEN TO_DATE( '2019-12-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd' ) AND TO_DATE( '2019-12-02', 'yyyy-mm-dd' );
```

It runs very fast because it is filtering on an indexed column.

The second query is like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST_TABLE
WHERE NOT_INDEXED_DATE_COLUMN BETWEEN TO_DATE( '2019-12-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd' ) AND TO_DATE( '2019-12-02', 'yyyy-mm-dd' );
```

The second query runs very slow. I don't have permission to create the index on that column and I have been asked to write the query so that it somehow runs fast, without the index. I would like to create the index and be done with it, but that is not an option due to things outside of my control in the particular situation.

So how can query two be modified to run fast like the first one?

UPDATE: INDEXED_DATE_COLUMN and NOT_INDEXED_DATE_COLUMN are in the same table. Just including that info in case it helps to solve this.

Comment: How do you expect your database to run the query as fast as if the column was indexed, but without an index? This sounds quite impossible to solve.

Comment: @GMB, that's what I thought and yet here I am being asked to do it. Maybe there's a way to get the NOT_INDEXED_DATE_COLUMN values from the table using the INDEXED_DATE_COLUMN. Sorry I should have said that earlier, that those two columns are in the same table. I will update the question with that info.

Comment: Tell whoever is asking you to do it to learn about how databases work. If you can't create an index to speed the filtering, you're simply never going to get the performance you'd get with an index. Wasting time trying to do so is just that - a waste of time. It's not possible. (And if you could get the *NOT_INDEXED_DATE_ COLUMN* from the table using the *INDEXED_DATE_COLUMN*, why can't you just query against the table with the `INDEXED_DATE_COLUMN` directly?)

Comment: If you have telephone directory with and without indexes then which will be much faster for you to search the contact?

Comment: Well, there is a way. Delete ~95% rows from that table. You should see improvement.

Comment: Will, if you have the partitioning option, partition your table on that column. But I suppose that if you cannot create an index, you won't be allowed to do that either. If you're on a recent version, you may be able to do that online.

Answer (score 0):

One way to run the query faster is to partition your table based on the NOT_INDEXED_DATE_COLUMN column. In this case, you can use range based partition.